# Position buttons next to each other in the center of page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the two buttons next to each other in the center of the page and also make the buttons static as you resize the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<style>
#button1{
width: 300px;
height: 40px;

}
#button2{
width: 300px;
height: 40px;
}
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Homepage" content="Starting page for the survey website ">

 <title> Survey HomePage</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="kingstonunilogo.jpg" alt="uni logo" style="width:180px;height:160px">
 <button type="button home-button" id="button1" >Home</button>
 <button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Contact Us</button>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "side by side"?

Comment: I mean have them next to each other, with the above code they are next to each other but change position as you resize the page. Also i'd like to have them side by side in the centre of the page.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you may want to consider using a more semantic `<nav><a href="/home">Home</a></nav>` sort of navigation rather than using buttons.

Comment: I get them next to each other but they are always starting at the left side of the container. Cannot get the two buttons to center.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can add this style to your buttons:

```
#button1 , #button2 {
display:inline-block;
/* additional code */
}
```

this aligns your buttons inline. ('side by side') :)

Comment: That doesn't put them in the center of the page.

Comment: How to decide the space between the two buttons?

Comment: you can use margin for space between them

Comment: Where is the "in the center of the page" part?

Answer (score 11):

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mgtoz4d3/

I added a container which contains both buttons. Try this:

CSS:

```
#button1{
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
}
#button2{
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
}
#container{
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="kingstonunilogo.jpg" alt="uni logo" style="width:180px;height:160px">
<br><br>
<div id="container">
    <button type="button home-button" id="button1" >Home</button>
    <button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Contact Us</button>
</div>
```

Comment: In the jsfiddle, if you resize the result window long enough, the buttons place next to each other.

Answer (score 10):

This can be solved using the following `CSS`:

```
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`display: inline-block` will put the buttons side by side and `text-align: center` places the buttons in the center of the page.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/026tbk13/

Answer (score 0):

**jsFiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/7Laf8/1302/

I hope this answers your question.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button">Hello</button>
  <button class="button">Another One</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize regular buttons and set the display property to inline in order to center the buttons on a single line. Setting the display property to inline-block will also put them on the same line, but they will not be centered via that display property setting.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.button{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="button">Button1</button>
  <button class="button">Button2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have both the buttons inside a div as shown below and add the given CSS for that div

```css
#button1, #button2{
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
}

#butn{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="butn">
 <button type="button home-button" id="button1" >Home</button>
 <button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Contact Us</button>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will look something like this ...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<style>
#button1{
width: 300px;
height: 40px;

}
#button2{
width: 300px;
height: 40px;
}
display:inline-block;
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Homepage" content="Starting page for the survey website ">

 <title> Survey HomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<img src="kingstonunilogo.jpg" alt="uni logo" style="width:180px;height:160px">
 <button type="button home-button" id="button1" >Home</button>
 <button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Contact Us</button>
</center>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then the below solution will work.

```html
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Invoke User Endpoint</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-3">Invoke Hello Endpoint</button>
</div>
```